# xml error: Non white space characters cannot be added to content

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I am trying to open an xmldocument like this:

```
var doc = new XDocument("c:\\temp\\contacts.xml");
var reader = doc.CreateReader();
var namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(reader.NameTable);
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("g", g.NamespaceName);
var node = doc.XPathSelectElement("/Contacts/Contact/g:Name[text()='Patrick Hines']", namespaceManager);
node.Value = "new name Richard";
doc.Save("c:\\temp\\newcontacts.xml");
```

I returns an error in the first line:

```
Non whitespace characters cannot be added to content.
```

The xmlfile looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Contacts xmlns:g="http://something.com">
  <Contact>
    <g:Name>Patrick Hines</g:Name>
    <Phone>206-555-0144</Phone>
    <Address>
      <street>this street</street>
    </Address>
  </Contact>
</Contacts>
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It looks like you're attempting to load an XML file into an XDocument, but to do so you need to call `XDocument.Load("C:\\temp\\contacts.xml");` - you can't pass an XML file into the constructor.

You can also load a string of XML with `XDocument.Parse(stringXml);`.

Change your first line to:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load("c:\\temp\\contacts.xml");
```

And it will work.

For reference, there are 4 overloads of the `XDocument` constructor:

```
XDocument();
XDocument(Object[]);
XDocument(XDocument);
XDocument(XDeclaration, Object[]);
```

You might have been thinking of the third one (`XDocument(XDocument)`), but to use that one you'd have to write:

```
var doc = new XDocument(XDocument.Load("c:\\temp\\contacts.xml"));
```

Which would be redundant when `var doc = XDocument.Load("c:\\temp\\contacts.xml");` will suffice.

See [XDocument Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.xdocument.aspx) for the gritty details.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
XDocument.Parse(stringxml)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument xdoc=XDocument.load(path)
```